# How to not unmarsal nested JSON in Golang

Tags: json, go

I have some JSON that I wish to unmarshal in Go. One of the top-level keys of the JSON dictionary has a value that is also parsable JSON. For example:

```
{ 
    "Name": "Tony",
    "Age": 50,
    "Extra": {\"Weight\":180}
}
```

I have a corresponding struct that I want to unmarsal to:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Extra []byte
 }
```

I want the `Extra` key to be a byte array because the JSON structure will vary and the structure of it is not important to the program being written. The program simply needs to push this data along down the line as a byte array.

How can I coax the Go JSON encoder to handle the value of `extra` like this?

Comment: [RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If you provide this as an answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

#### Using `json.RawMessage`

Here you have to slightly change your struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Extra *json.RawMessage
}
```

then, you can `Unmarshal` as usual

```
person := Person{}
err := json.Unmarshal(raw_bytes, &person)
// handle err
```

finally, you can Unmarshal `Extra` again, you can even do some assertion type on it to previously detect the type

```
var extra_option_1 string
extra_option_2 := AnotherStruct{}

err := json.Unmarshal(raw_bytes, &extra_option_1)
// handle err
    
// or
    
err := json.Unmarshal(raw_bytes, &extra_option_2)
// handle err
```

---

#### Using `map[string]interface{}{}` - honestly not so useful in your case

You can directly unmarshal "unknown" or dynamics payloads using a general `map[string]interface{}{}`.
BUT I discourage this usage because is slower and you should always know what to expect.

Anyway, hereafter is a pseudo code:

```
payload := map[string]interface{}{}
err := json.Unmarshal(raw_bytes, &payload)
// handle err
```

In this last case, you need even to do assertion to each field.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json.RawMessage`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) or `interface{}`:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Extra json.RawMessage
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
    Extra interface{}
}
```

With a json.RawMessage, the data is pushed down the line as a slice of bytes.  With an `interface{}`, the data is unmarshaled to Go values (bool, float64, string, []interface{}, map[string]interface{}, nil) and marshaled back to JSON. Both options pass arbitrary JSON through the application. If the application does not have a reason to use one or the other, then `json.RawMessage` is probably the better choice because it's faster.

Comment: Another answer suggests using `map[string]interface{}`, but this type cannot represent arbitrary JSON.  Another answer also suggests using `*json.RawMessage`.  This works, but the extra level of indirection does not provide any value.